# Can one user message map to multiple intents or actions in dialogflow?

Tags: bots, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Can one user message map to multiple intents or actions in dialogflow?
Example: i have two intents
1) Restaurants
2) pizzadelivery

User message= I am hungry

Can we have bot map this user message to both intents and give nearby restaurant recommendation and pizza options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no.

Intents represent *what the user says*, **not** what you expect the response to be.

In your example, the phrase "I am hungry" should map to something that might be named "user.hungry". Other phrases that would do this might be "I'd like some food" or "I'd like to eat". It is then up to you to figure out a reply. That reply might be based on other things you know about the user (such as their location or food preference), or based on other things you may need to know.

It may or may not be different than an Intent that would handle "I want some pizza" or "I want some Chinese food". Those phrases might be the same, but also contain food preference information.

It probably would be a different Intent if the user asked for something to drink - although the results might be the same.

Remember - Intents represent what the user says. Not how you reply.

Comment: Thanks!! This was really helpful. My understanding of what intents are was incorrect.

Comment: Almost all of us had the same misunderstanding early on. Glad it helped!

Comment: I have a follow up question, If I have two intents order pizza and play music and the message is "I want to order pizza and play {rock} music". Now two different intents were mentioned by user in one sentence. How would dialogflow behave in this case?

Comment: That is a different question, and I suggest you post it as a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: (Or try it out and post if you have questions about how it behaved.)